# Creating listview with rounded corner shows partial corners

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to create a listview with rounded corners but for some reason not all the corners get rounded. This is how it looks like

[image]

I created the background with the following code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/app_grey_color" />
    <corners android:radius="8dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

I have the following in my layout file

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/third_section"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/second_section"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/heading"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10sp"
                    android:text="Contact us"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_grey_color"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.3dp"
                android:padding="10sp"
                android:layout_margin="10sp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/contact_us_list_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see from the image you post in your question.

Your ListView is overlaping your border somehow.
    Try giving the padding to your listview.

```
<ListView
   android:id="@+id/contact_us_list_view"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:divider="@null"
   android:dividerHeight="0dp"
   android:padding="10dp"              // OverHere
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

what else i can see in your layout is that you are using "sp" instead of "dp"
in many places.

Comment: The `sp` was based on a recommendation from android studios. In any case i <3 you because it works!!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some padding to your LinearLayout. It looks like your listview background color is just overlapping the background.